# Sqlalchemy query with_entities for multiple table name

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Below is my code.

```
sometable1.query.with_entities(
    sometable2.user,
    sometable3.user_name,
    seomtable4.user
).join(
    sometable2,
    sometable2.user_id == sometable1.user_id
).join(
    sometable3,
    sometable3.user_id==sometable2.user_id
).join(
    sometable4,
    sometable4.user_id==sometable3.user_id
).filter(
    sometable1.user_id==2
).all()
```

The above query gives the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't determine which FROM clause to join from, 
there are multiple 
FROMS which can join to this entity. Please use the .select_from()
```

But when i add sometable1.user in the query then its working fine.

```
sometable1.query.with_entities(
    sometable1.user,   #<-------------- added sometable1.user
    sometable2.user,
    sometable3.user_name,
    seomtable4.user
).join(
    sometable2,
    sometable2.user_id == sometable1.user_id
).join(
    sometable3,
    sometable3.user_id==sometable2.user_id
).join(
    sometable4,
    sometable4.user_id==sometable3.user_id
).filter(
    sometable1.user_id==2
).all()
```

I don't want sometable1.user, is there any way to remove it ?
The output gives sometable1.user along with other data in a list.
But i dont want sometable1.user in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
sometable1.query.with_entities(
    sometable2.user,
    sometable3.user_name,
    seomtable4.user
).select_from(   #<-------------- select_from
  sometable1
).join(
    sometable2,
    sometable2.user_id == sometable1.user_id
).join(
    sometable3,
    sometable3.user_id==sometable2.user_id
).join(
    sometable4,
    sometable4.user_id==sometable3.user_id
).filter(
    sometable1.user_id==2
).all()
```

Have to use select_from then include sometable1.